# Which I should choose?

Tags: verbs

> These....views of your desktop allow you to group applications together.

A. separate

B. separates

C. separating

D. separated

Which should I choose option?

Answer (score 1):

You might want the *adjective*, A.

> These **separate** views of your desktop allow you to group applications together.

B. *3rd person present*

> The view *separates*...

C. *present participle*

> The views *separating* the applications...

D. *past participle*

> The applications are *separated*...

But you can use **separated** as an adjective, too.

Comment: So A and D both are correct . B and c are wrong?

Comment: B and C cannot be used at this place. There is other ways of phrasing this sentence though.